# Embed html5 banner inside another html page

Tags: html

I have a html5 banner that I've been supplied with that has some animations and so on. How would I embed this inside an already existing html document? I don't want to grab the code from the html5 document, instead it would be nice if I could link to the html5 banner..

I don't know if this is possible though.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- Embed html5 banner here -->
        <div src="/assets/html5banner.html" /> <!-- Something like that, I don't know -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Any push in the right direction would really be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Okay the question has been answered.. Use an iframe, don't know why I didn't think of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `iframe` to embed other html document into your page

```
<iframe src="#"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

[iFrames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp#gsc.tab=0) are your friends.

```
<iframe src="/htmlanim.html"></iframe>
```

You can also be fancy-shmancy and use Ajax to append the content dynamically to an empty `<div>`-Container.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use an iframe.